# Align the text in the toolbar with the icons

Tags: android, xml

Here's how my toolbar currently looks. The text seems completely mislaid.

[image]

Here's the code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:background="@color/blue_grey_900"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ToolbarPopup"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:elevation="5dp"/>
```

What's causing the misalignment?

Comment: how are u adding the back icon?

Comment: @royB getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your code to `android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize`

Comment: Doesn't change anything.

Comment: did you also change the `minHeight`? if so please show us the `popupTheme` styel

Comment: Okay, I got it working by changing layout_height to wrap_content and android:minHeight= to "?attr/actionBarSize"

Comment: For me, my issue started when `layout_height` was `wrap_content` and `minHeight` was omitted. I added `minHeight` as `?attr/actionBarSize` but it had no effect. I was able to omit minHeight completely, and just changing `layout_height` to `?attr/actionBarSize` fixed my issue where it was misaligned on device rotation. So the original answer happened to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom `TextView` in your XML like:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="56dp"
android:background="@color/blue_grey_900"
android:gravity="center"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
app:popupTheme="@style/ToolbarPopup"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
android:elevation="5dp">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Title"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Then you can customize it or place the title anywhere you want.

Comment: there is no reason to add a title textView only for gravity location, specially if he only needs to align to the back button. his problem involves styling